# Trying to pass variables outside of input functions Python

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I am trying to get `col_number` and `user_input` to be recognized outside of the input function.

The only way I seem to be able to use the `col_number` outside the input function is if I define a global variable inside - which doesn't seem right. I have tried placing the statement above the `def get_input` but get a 'col_number might be referenced before assignment.

I need to use the `user_input` as a txt string for a header on a graph but don't understand how to pass it out. The print statement last line in the code gives me an unresolved reference.

Any suggestions please.

```
 col_number = int
def get_input(prompt):
        #global col_number
        #locals col_number
        global col_number
        while True:
            user_input = input(prompt).lower()
            if user_input in ('apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'quit'):
    # the user = int(0),int(1), int(2) values just assign a different column numnber
                if user_input == 'apples':
                    col_number = 0
                if user_input == 'pears':
                    col_number = 1
                if user_input == 'oranges':
                    col_number = 2
            return col_number, user_input

print(get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit'))
print(user_input)
```

Comment: `col_number = int` isn't what you think it is, it looks like you're trying to reassign the type `int` to `col_number`. Did you mean `col_number = int()`?

Comment: @G.Anderson is right.  If you're trying to use a [type hint](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html), you want `col_number: int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never declare `user_input` as a global variable. You could fix this problem by adding `user_input=""` before the function and adding `global user_input` after the other global statement, but this is an unpythonic way to return values from a function. Instead, you should assign the result of the function to variables, for example: `col_number, user_input = get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit')`. By doing this, you can access these values and also remove `col_number = int` and `global col_number` as they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

You are not *defining* the global variable inside.  The [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) is telling the Python interpreter to use the `col_number` object created in the [`global` scope](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) instead of creating a new local scope object named `col_number`.

A better way to approach this would be to assign the returned objects from your function instead of pre-defining them:

```
def get_input(prompt):
   while True:
        user_input = input(prompt).lower()
        if user_input in ('apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'quit'):
            if user_input == 'apples':
                col_number = 0
            if user_input == 'pears':
                col_number = 1
            if user_input == 'oranges':
                col_number = 2
        # I think this next line should be indented?
        # I left it here as is to reference your code but it'll error out
        # if the input is not valid since col_number will not be created.
        return col_number, user_input

# Assign and make use of your returned objects!
my_col, my_input = get_input('Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit')
print(my_col)
print(my_input)
```

It's best to avoid referencing global variables within functions as it can get messy the more complex your code becomes.

Answer (score 1):

To get `user_input` out of `get_input` you have a couple options:

**Declare a variable from the function:**

```py
col_num, usr_inpt = get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit')
print(usr_inpt)
```

**Make user_input a global variable.**

```py
col_number = 0
user_input = None
def get_input(prompt):
    global col_number
    global user_input
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt).lower()
        if user_input in ('apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'quit'):
            # the user = int(0),int(1), int(2) values just assign a different column numnber
            if user_input == 'apples':
                col_number = 0
            if user_input == 'pears':
                col_number = 1
            if user_input == 'oranges':
                col_number = 2
        return col_number, user_input

print(get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit'))
print(user_input)
```

But, as @r.ook pointed out, it's usually a bad idea to use globals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that - ive been looking at that all day1 for that its working now I am trying to include the 'break' line to quit out for the final part. It works but crashes out instead. I am missing something else.

```
def get_input(prompt):

    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt).lower()
        if user_input in ('apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'quit'):
            # the user = int(0),int(1), int(2) values just assign a different column numnber
            if user_input == 'apples':
                col_number = 0
            if user_input == 'pears':
                col_number = 1
            if user_input == 'oranges':
                col_number = 2
            if user_input == 'quit':
                break
            return col_number, user_input


my_col, my_input = get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit')
print(my_input)
```

Comment: Instead of `break`, use `col_number = None` or something, so that your `return` statement won't error out.  Otherwise it'll break the loop and return nothing for your function, making your object assignment for the returned objects giving unpacking error.